# sound playes sometimes in apple watch

Tags: swift, audio, apple-watch

i'm tring to play a sound whenever a certian condition is met.
this function accurs every second:

```swift
if (currentIndexInPredictionWindow == ModelConstants.predictionWindowSize) {
    let InpVect = userAccelX + userAccelY + userAccelZ + quaternionX + quaternionY + quaternionZ + quaternionW + gravityX + gravityY + gravityZ
    myNeuralNetworkFunction_initialize()
    myNeuralNetworkFunction(InpVect, OutputPointer)
    let res0 = OutputPointer[0]
    let res1 = OutputPointer[1]

    if (res0 > 0.6) {                
        WKInterfaceDevice.current().play(.success)
        //playSound()
        touches += 1
        print ("touch!")
    }
    currentIndexInPredictionWindow = 0
}
```

i tried this with play(.success) and also with AVAudioPlayer (the func playSound) and in both cases it doesn't play every time i call the function.
strangely, if i place the command play(.success) outside of the inner if statement, it does play every second.
does someone have any idea what can cause this?

Answer (score 0):

It may cause because you didn't play the sound inside the Main Thread try using

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
     WKInterfaceDevice.current().play(.success)
}
```

It should be ok I think

Comment: it still playes sometimes:(

Comment: so in this case the only thing that I think may works is setting the else for your if condition specially if it called on the list